# How can I elegantly combine resource and exception handling?

Tags: clojure, macros, resources, lisp

I'm writing a Clojure wrapper for an object-oriented API that heavily involves resource handling. For instance, for the Foo object, I've written three basic functions: `foo?`, which returns `true` iff something is a Foo; `create-foo`, which attempts to obtain the resources to create a Foo, then returns a map containing a return code and (if the construction succeeded) the newly created Foo; and `destroy-foo`, which takes a Foo and releases its resources. Here are some stubs for those three functions:

```clj
(def foo? (comp boolean #{:placeholder}))

(defn create-foo []
  (let [result (rand-nth [::success ::bar-too-full ::baz-not-available])]
    (merge {::result result}
           (when (= ::success result)
             {::foo :placeholder}))))

(defn destroy-foo [foo] {:pre [(foo? foo)]} nil)
```

Obviously, every time `create-foo` is called and succeeds, `destroy-foo` must be called with the returned Foo. Here's a simple example that doesn't use any custom macros:

```clj
(let [{:keys [::result ::foo]} (create-foo)]
  (if (= ::success result)
    (try
      (println "Got a Foo:")
      (prn foo)
      (finally
        (destroy-foo foo)))
    (do
      (println "Got an error:")
      (prn result))))
```

There's a lot of boilerplate here: the `try`-`finally`-`destroy-foo` construct must be present to ensure that all Foo resources are released, and the `(= ::success result)` test must be present to ensure that nothing gets run assuming a Foo when there is no Foo.

Some of that boilerplate can be eliminated by a `with-foo` macro, similar to the [`with-open`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open) macro in `clojure.core`:

```clj
(defmacro with-foo [bindings & body]
  {:pre [(vector? bindings)
         (= 2 (count bindings))
         (symbol? (bindings 0))]}
  `(let ~bindings
     (try
       ~@body
       (finally
         (destroy-foo ~(bindings 0))))))
```

While this does help somewhat, it doesn't do anything about the `(= ::success result)` boilerplate, and now *two* separate binding forms are required to achieve the desired result:

```clj
(let [{:keys [::result] :as m} (create-foo)]
  (if (= ::success result)
    (with-foo [foo (::foo m)]
      (println "Got a Foo:")
      (prn foo))
    (do
      (println "Got an error:")
      (prn result))))
```

I simply can't figure out a good way to handle this. I mean, I could complect the behaviors of [`if-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let) and `with-foo` into some sort of `if-with-foo` macro:

```clj
(defmacro if-with-foo [bindings then else]
  {:pre [(vector? bindings)
         (= 2 (count bindings))]}
  `(let [{result# ::result foo# ::foo :as m#} ~(bindings 1)
         ~(bindings 0) m#]
     (if (= ::success result#)
       (try
         ~then
         (finally
           (destroy-foo foo#)))
       ~else)))
```

This does eliminate even more boilerplate:

```clj
(if-with-foo [{:keys [::result ::foo]} (create-foo)]
  (do
    (println "Got a Foo:")
    (prn foo))
  (do
    (println "Got a result:")
    (prn result)))
```

However, I don't like this `if-with-foo` macro for several reasons:

- it's very tightly coupled to the specific structure of the map returned by `create-foo`
- unlike `if-let`, it causes all bindings to be in scope in both branches
- its ugly name reflects its ugly complexity

Are these macros the best I can do here? Or is there a more elegant way to handle resource handling with possible resource obtainment failure? Perhaps this is a job for [monads](/questions/tagged/monads); I don't have enough experience with monads to know whether they would be useful tool here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from @murphy's excellent idea to put the error handler into `with-foo`'s `bindings` to keep the focus on the normal case, I've ended up with a solution that I like quite a lot:

```clj
(defmacro with-foo [bindings & body]
  {:pre [(vector? bindings)
         (even? (count bindings))]}
  (if-let [[sym init temp error] (not-empty bindings)]
    (let [error? (= :error temp)]
      `(let [{result# ::result foo# ::foo :as m#} ~init]
         (if (contains? m# ::foo)
           (try
             (let [~sym foo#]
               (with-foo ~(subvec bindings (if error? 4 2))
                 ~@body))
             (finally
               (destroy-foo foo#)))
           (let [f# ~(if error? error `(constantly nil))]
             (f# result#)))))
    `(do
       ~@body)))
```

- like my `if-with-foo` macro in the question, this `with-foo` macro is still tied to the structure returned by `create-foo`; *unlike* my `if-with-foo` macro and @murphy's `with-foo` macro, it eliminates the need for the user to manually take apart that structure
- all names are properly scoped; the user's `sym` is only bound in the main `body`, *not* in the `:error` handler, and conversely, the `::result` is only bound in the `:error` handler, *not* in the main `body`
- like @murphy's solution, this macro has a nice, fitting name, instead of something ugly like `if-with-foo`
- unlike @murphy's `with-foo` macro, this `with-foo` macro allows the user to provide any `init` value, rather than forcing a call to `create-foo`, and doesn't transform the returned value

The most basic use case simply binds a symbol to a Foo returned by `create-foo` in some `body`, returning `nil` if the construction fails:

```clj
(with-foo [foo (create-foo)]
  ["Got a Foo!" foo])
```

To handle the exceptional case, an `:error` handler can be added to the binding:

```clj
(with-foo [foo (create-foo)
           :error (partial vector "Got an error!")]
  ["Got a Foo!" foo])
```

Any number of Foo bindings can be used:

```clj
(with-foo [foo1 (create-foo)
           foo2 (create-foo)]
  ["Got some Foos!" foo1 foo2])
```

Each binding can have its own `:error` handler; any missing error handlers are replaced with `(constantly nil)`:

```clj
(with-foo [foo1 (create-foo)
           :error (partial vector "Got an error!")
           foo2 (create-foo)]
  ["Got some Foos!" foo1 foo2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add an error-handler to `with-foo`. This way the macro has a focus on what should be done. However, this simplifies the code only when all error-cases are treated by a handful of error handlers. If you have to define a custom error-handler every time you call `with-foo` this solution makes readability worse than an if-else construct.

I added `copy-to-map`. `copy-to-map` should copy all relevant information from the object to a map. This way the user of the macro doesn't by accident return the foo-object, since it gets destroyed inside the macro

```clj
(defn foo? [foo]
  (= ::success (:result foo)))

(defn create-foo [param-one param-two]
  (rand-nth (map #(merge {:obj :foo-obj :result %} {:params [param-one param-two]})
                 [::success ::bar-too-full ::baz-not-available])))

(defn destroy-foo [foo]
      nil)

(defn err-handler [foo]
      [:error foo])

(defn copy-to-map [foo]
      ;; pseudo code here
      (into {} foo))

(defmacro with-foo [[f-sym foo-params & {:keys [on-error]}] & body]
  `(let [foo# (apply ~create-foo [~@foo-params])
         ~f-sym (copy-to-map foo#)]
     (if (foo? foo#)
       (try ~@body
            (finally (destroy-foo foo#)))
       (when ~on-error
         (apply ~on-error [~f-sym])))))
```

Now you call it

```clj
(with-foo [f [:param-one :param-two] :on-error err-handler]
    [:success (str "i made it: " f)])
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following your solution; also, when I run your example code, I get a `clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: create-foo`.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote your example a little bit to experiment withit myself.
I update it with my version that is different from yours but works.

Comment: @SamEstep Now it works with cut and paste
What is unclear? I'm glad to help

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Your `copy-to-map` function is irrelevant, because the real object I'm working with is opaque. There are some confusing inconsistencies in your `with-foo` macro, but I think I get the idea now. I like how it places the focus on the normal case, which allows it to keep the nicer `with-foo` name. However, it seems like your code has redefined "Foo" to mean "a map containing the `:result`, `:params`, and `:obj` from a `create-foo` call" (even going so far as to include `create-foo` directly inside `with-foo`), which is a rather tight coupling that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Your opaque object will not help, if I'm not mistaken. In your `if-with-foo` version the last thing you do is `(prn foo)`. However, what if you simply "return" foo: 
 `...  (with-foo [foo (::foo m)]  foo) ...` Then the user gets back a foo object that is destroyed in the finally block in your macro . if you add a (prn :destroy_foo)  to your destroy_foo function, you will see, that the destructor is called before the result is printed.

Comment: My idea of less thight coupled was that in my macro you need  only the function `foo?` and `destroy_foo`, not more knowledge about the structure of the foo-object, if you want different behavior for different structures , you may use multimethod/protocols for the implementation of `foo?`/`destroy_foo`  IMHO this is less tight coupled

Comment: I understand the potential for returning an invalid object; however, if a Foo is opaque, what exactly could `copy-to-map` do besides just returning an empty map? And what if the user doesn't return just a raw Foo, but rather a Foo buried inside of some data structure? It wouldn't make sense to spend a lot of effort taking apart and reconstructing the returned value just to try to avoid the possibility of the user returning an invalid object; that's simply not something that can be effectively prevented.

Comment: With your macro, the user still needs to destructure the "foo map" in the `:on-error` handler in order to retrieve the `:result` code, in addition to destructuring the same map in the `body` in order to retrieve the Foo `:obj` in order to pass that Foo to other functions. Your `with-open` macro does nothing to hide the structure returned by `create-foo` from the user.

Comment: `copy-to-map` is just a dummy. hence the comment "pseudo code".  The idea here is that you have to know what fields from the object you want to expose to the user and copy that into a map. the user then works with that map and you can safely dispose the opaque object.

Comment: As I said, the object is *opaque*, meaning it *has no public fields*.

Comment: tight coupling:

objects are often represented as hashes in clojure, so a map representation is not unusual for that. if you want a more opaque object, you should have a look into protocols.

Comment: No, the Foo object itself, in the API that I am wrapping, has no public fields. I'm not creating a new data structure; I'm simply writing a set of functions and macros for dealing with Foo objects, which are already defined in an opaque way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120863/discussion-between-murphy-and-sam-estep).

Comment: Are you implying that Clojure's error handing is so awful that the `with-foo` macro can't just throw an exception? I'm genuinely asking. Coming from a Common Lisp background, I would never feel the need to build an error handler directly into a macro.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million Of course you could [`throw`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/throw) an exception; that's pretty ugly and not very [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), though.

Comment: @murphy I still don't quite understand what you're going for with the protocols, but your idea about the error handler led me to what I think is a [pretty good solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38945416/5044950). Thank you for your insight!