# A Clojure function that always returns nil

Tags: clojure

Is there a function in Clojure that always returns nil no matter what the input is?

I know I could write (fn [_] nil) but is there a built-in function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `constantly` to return a function which always returns the given value e.g.

```
(constantly nil)
```

Note the returned function takes an arbitrary number of parameters while yours only allows one.

Comment: If you didn't want to use constantly for some reason, you could modify the literal function to accept any number of arguments by typing:  `(fn [& args] nil)`

Comment: @AlanThompson Anyone can figure that out by looking at the source for [`constantly`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1396). But more importantly, why would you not want to use `constantly`?

Answer (score 4):

[`constantly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/constantly) is the function you are looking for:

```
((constantly nil) 2)
=> nil
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just, like, use the CONSTANT 'nil'?  Why is calling a function a superior thing to do in your book?

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner Why did you post your comment on this answer instead of on the question?

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner For instance, you may find yourself expecting an anonymous function that may or may not return a desired value. In such cases `constantly` can act as a fallback option. It also proves very useful in tests.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38945416/5044950) of an arguably useful piece of code I wrote recently that makes use of `(constantly nil)`.